# Install provision file on Mac for Mac apps，returns "Provisioning profile does not allow this device."

Tags: macos, provisioning

Install provision file on Mac for Mac apps.
returns "Provisioning profile does not allow this device."

[image]

Comment: have you created  account on apple developer account

Comment: Yes , I have .
I've found the reason : I did not register the current Mac UUID. After register the device and edit the provison file ,download the  newest provision file ,I can install it successully .

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned that have you created account on Apple developer account. But i assume that you have already created an account on  [Apple](http://developer.apple.com). Login into your mac PC

1. Start XCode
2. Select XCode Menu
3. Go To preferences.
4. A Screen will be open
5. Go To Account Section
6. Click on Download Manual Profile

Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you a lot !
I've found the reason : I did not register the current Mac UUID. After register the device and edit the provison file ,download the  newest provision file ,I can install it successully